# Using contextlib.redirect_stdout in an async function redirects output of other tasks

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, stdout

I want to redirect the output of a few lines in my code that I don't have control over, but the outputs are not relevant. I've been able to use `contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO())` in a synchronous function to successfully redirect the lines I want, but I can't do it with an async function

This is what I have so far

```py
import asyncio
import contextlib
import sys

async def long_function(val: int, semaphore: asyncio.Semaphore, file_out, old_stdout=sys.stdout):
    
    # Only let two tasks start at a time
    await semaphore.acquire()
    print(f"{val}: Starting")
        
    # Redirect stdout of ONLY the lines within this context manager
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file_out):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)  # long-running task that prints output I can't control, but is not useful to me
        print(f"{val}: Finished redirect")
    contextlib.redirect_stdout(old_stdout)
        
    print(f"{val}: Done")
    semaphore.release()

async def main():
    # I want to limit the number of concurrent tasks to 2
    semaphore: asyncio.Semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
    
    # Create a list of tasks to perform
    file_out = open("file.txt", "w")
    tasks = []
    for i in range(0, 9):
        tasks.append(long_function(i, semaphore, file_out))
    
    # Gather/run the tasks
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When running this, however, the output of other tasks is also placed into the "file.txt" file. I only want the "Finished redirect" to be placed into the file

I see the following in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html)

> Note that the global side effect on sys.stdout means that this context manager is not suitable for use in library code and most threaded applications. It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses. However, it is still a useful approach for many utility scripts.

Is there any other way to go about this, or do I just have to live with the output as-is?

Thanks for any help!